# XML syntax highlighting for [kml] tag

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

[kml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kml) is [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml)-based language so its code need XML syntax highlighting.

[xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml) has

> "Code Language (used for [syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xml/info)): lang-xml".

Look at the bottom of [XML tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xml/info). We should have the same for [kml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kml).

Both [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml) and [kml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kml) can be used with any language but XML questions have proper syntax highlighting and KML questions don't. Examples with incorrect highlighting: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17235833/1548895), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12159647/1548895), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2486325/1548895) etc. To see the difference try to add [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml) tag to question or add HTML-comment `<!-- language: lang-xml -->` before KML code (but don't apply these edits until this [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) is considered).

Comment: KML is most often used with *other languages*; I rather not see `[python] [kml]` or `[r] [kml]` posts resort to the default 'just guess at highlighting' mode.

Comment: XML on the other hand has a lot of stand-alone 'how do I properly define this in XML' questions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If [tag:python], [tag:r] or other language is used in question apparently we would get syntax highlighting via tag, but if this suggestion won't be implemented we won't get syntax highlighting for KML code.

Comment: No, when multiple tags with a default language set are present on a question then [`language-default` is used](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I didn't get your points. [tag:xml] is also used with multiple languages and despite this I see proper syntax highlighting, but for [tag:kml] I don't.

Comment: You see the `default` highlighting, or post specifically sets a different language tag for code blocks with the `<!-- language: .. -->` or `<!-- language-all: ... -->` syntax. The XML tag still has a default set because there is a large enough body of posts with *only* the XML tag. I don't see that for KML.

Comment: Put differently, `language-default` still will apply *some* highlighting, but it is a generic brand of highlighting that often gets things wrong. This is not the same as `language-none`, which would disable all highlighting.

Comment: [tag:xml] has "Code Language (used for [syntax highlighting](https://github.com/google/code-prettify)): lang-xml". Look at the bottom of [XML tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xml/info). 
Why can't we have the same for [tag:kml]?

Comment: I think what Martijn Pieters meant is: are there any standalone KML code questions without referencing to another language (or, being language agnostic)? By finding these (hopefully on-topic) questions, then there might be a benefit in this feature request. Alternative workaround is to tag it with [tag:xml] since it's an XML. Otherwise, there's no point in adding a syntax highlighting if it's never used (or worse, conflicts with another language's syntax highlighting).

Comment: Never mind, I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48926771/2821954). However, I think Martijn's concern about reverting to `language-default` is a bigger concern, so we have to judge if the advantages weights more than the disadvantages. I'd prefer to just add [tag:xml] tag since it's just a normal XML file though...

Comment: @AndrewT. I don't know about language-agnostic KML questions. I'm working with KML using C#. And when I find some [C# + KML question without XML tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+kml+-xml) it doesn't have proper syntax highlighting. Examples: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17235833/1548895), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12159647/1548895), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2486325/1548895) etc. And for any question with tag [tag:xml] everything works OK.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov I see... perhaps put your reasoning on the question to make this request more convincing. However, I still can see Martijn's concern if `default` syntax highlighting sometimes make it worse. Now it's just a matter to judge if the advantages outweigh the disadvantages...